# How do I access dropdown in SPAN within PHP POST form?

Tags: php, forms, post, html

I have a modification of the dynamic code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781558/how-do-i-create-a-series-of-js-php-drop-down-menus-that-automatically-populate-b) embedded within a PHP form, with span elements such as

```
<span level='0'></span> 
<span level='1'></span> 
<span level='2'></span>
```

in the form.

**Each span will contain a `<select>` dropdown that needs to be POSTed**

Each span is filled using a JS function exactly like the one in the link, which calls the shown ajax.php file to fill the dropdowns.

These values do not POST with my form, presumably because SPANs may not be processed as part of the POST array. Is there a way I can modify this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the details of the link, but it seems you could use a form element such as  instead of `<span>` to post the data that you need, and just use JS to set the value of this element accordingly.

**Edit:** An example. I may be misinterpreting your question. What is the data that is important to you - The level at which the user selected? So, if I make a selection from the `<span level='1'></span>` `<select>`, you need to know that I chose level 1? In this case, since you're pulling that from the DB through AJAX anyway, I would check it on the server side using PHP to determine the chosen level. Otherwise, you can do something similar to the following.

Note: This will only set the hidden element to the level of the last changed `<select>`.

```
<form>
    <span level="0">
        <select onchange="javascript: $('#input_span_level').val('0');"></select>
    </span>
    <span level="1">
        <select onchange="javascript: $('#input_span_level').val('1');"></select>
    </span>

    <input id="input_span_level" type="hidden" name="span_level" value="-1" />
</form>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I'm pretty new to PHP/JS, so would you mind please seeing if the code in the link is compatible? I'm not sure how I would implement your solution.

Comment: No, I'm interested in the value selected by the user for each of the three dropdowns. I use AJAX to script through and fill each dropdown with choices using PHP on the server. The JS takes this HTML and places it into the span.

I originally thought this would act like any other dropdown in a POST form, but apparently it does not POST because it is in a SPAN

Comment: So when the user submits the POST form, as long as the `<select>` elements are within the `<form>` tag, their values will be sent to the server and accessible in the `$_POST` array. It shouldn't matter that the `<select>` elements are encapsulated within `<span>`, you could change them to `<div>` and it would still work.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by that. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551724/php-accessing-span-values) post, you cannot access SPAN data within a post, so I am trying to figure out how I can get around this. Is there any way I can get that data outside the SPAN, into the post?

Comment: The data isn't really in a SPAN though, it's in a SELECT, which just happens to be inside a SPAN, correct? So, the SPAN doesn't matter, because it's not really holding the data, the SELECT is.

Comment: This might make things more clear. Opttwo is `POST`ed, while Optone is not: http://pastebin.com/vrRE2btT http://pastebin.com/ygW5YyFz